# Kshell read a file and define record length then strip ascii 20 characters from the end of each record

Tags: linux, scripting, sed, awk, ksh

I am moving a file transfer from an OpenVMS server over to a Unix server, and there is a VMS program that reads this file in record by record, defining a record length of 320, and then strips all ASCII 20 characters from the end of each record. How can I do this with a KSH script?

I just want to read a file in record by record, strip all ascii 20 characters from position 320 in each record back to where there is an actual good character (real end of the record), and write it out to a new file.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm on AIX 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed -i -r 's/(.{319})\x14(.*)$/\1\2/' file
```

This command will read first 319 character followed by `\x14` (ASCII 20) and then rest of the line. It will then put back matched group # 1 and matched group # 2. This will leave out `\x20`.

`-i` flag (inline) of sed will save the changed file back.

**EDIT:** Try this sed on AIX:

```
sed 's/\(.\{319\}\)'$'\x14''\(.*\)$/\1\2/' file > _temp && mv _temp file
```

**Final Solution:** After investigations (see comments) it was found that file had trailing spaces (hex 20) instead of ASCII 20. Once it was established following solution worked:

```
sed 's/ *$//' file > _temp && mv _temp file
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but -i and -r are both not recognized flags. It looks like this is an AIX server, sorry for not clarifying. Is there a different syntax?

Comment: Does AIX support `-E` flag in sed?

Comment: Yes, I can do -e with a script, if that helps!

Comment: `-E` is a flag for extended regex support actually. Can you please check man sed on AIX.

Comment: I have edited my answer and provided an alternate sed command for AIX. Try it pls.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it was capital E. AIX does not support that flag, it seems very limited. I tried the above EDIT but it says it cannot be parsed -

sed: 0602-404 Function s/\(.\{319\}\)$\x14\(.*\)$/\1\2/ cannot be parsed.

Comment: It doesn't look like it, sorry! Really appreciate the help though!

$ cut -c1-319 -c321- WLBINTDAY1.EXTR_WLB.COPY
Usage: cut -b List [-n] [File...]
   or: cut -c List [File...]
   or: cut -f List [-d Character] [-s] [File...]

Comment: Oh ok it doesn't support `cut -c`. Try this cut command: `cut -b1-319  WLBINTDAY1.EXTR_WLB.COPY`

Comment: It would support -c or -b, but it doesn't seem to like multiple -b or -c flags. If I just do "cut -b 1-319 MYFILE" or "cut -c 1-139 MYFILE" it prints to the screen, but I can't do -b 319 and -b 320

Comment: I did try "cut -b 1-319 MYFILE" and it printed it to the screen

Comment: ok `cut -c1-319 WLBINTDAY1.EXTR_WLB.COPY > _out` and examine `_out` file to see if 320th char was removed or not.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it does. I examined one record from _out and it looks like there is one less of the ascii 20 characters in the record in the _out file than in the original source. Now I just need to find out how to remove all of the ascii 20 characters from the end of each record!

Comment: Can ascii 20 character anywhere in file or just at at the 320th position?

Comment: They are used to pad the records, which are 320 in length, so they can be anywere from 320 inwards. I need to start at 320 and get rid of the ascii 20, then get rid of it at 319, 318, 317, etc. until I hit a normal (non-ascii 20) character - if that makes sense?

Comment: Hmm can you see if this sed works: `sed 's/'$'\x33''*$//' file`

Comment: I can execute that sed, but it looks exactly the same. I did sed 's/'$'\x33''*$//' WLBINTDAY1.EXTR_WLB > STRIPPED.txt and compared byte sites of input and output, they were identical.

Comment: oh sorry not `\X33` but `\X20`. Try `sed 's/'$'\x20''*$//' file`

Comment: Thanks, but that gives the same result. Doesn't seem to actually be deleting anything from the file, byte size of output is the same as the input with those characters, and file looks identical as well.

Comment: ok last attempt from my side: `sed -e 's/'$(echo -e "\024")'*$//' file`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, it had issues too. "Function s/-e cannot be parsed." - I will keep digging around trying to find a way to get this doneIt's a relatively straightforward concept, I just can't find the right syntax to actually do it.

Comment: Thanks, anubhava, same thing though! This doesn't seem to be changing anything either.

Comment: I will make one more attempt using awk. Try this command: `awk '{c=sprintf("%c", 20); gsub(c, ""); print}' file > _out` and then examine output file.

Comment: Thanks, anubhava, no luck there either! The output was the same as the input.

Comment: Hmm can you tell me what you get when you enter: `awk 'BEGIN {printf("%c\n", 65)}'` ?

Comment: Which is good, now can you take one line of your file (where you have ascii 20) and do `od -bc` on it and paste the output in your question.

Comment: The output is too long but it looks like this, 

$ od -bc onerecord
0000000  063 070 063 067 066 114 101 112 070 062 060 061 060 060 071 061
           3   8   3   7   6   L   A   J   8   2   0   1   0   0   9   1
0000020  106 113 040 107 116 122 101 040 107 101 062 060 040 040 060 056
           F   K       G   N   R   A       G   A   2   0           0   .
0000040  066 062 061 066 040 040 067 057 062 060 057 064 060 060 060 060
           6   2   1   6           7   /   2   0   /   4   0   0   0   0
0000060  060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060 060

Comment: I don't see `024` in your output which actually is ascii 20.

Comment: Hi anubhava, now that i'm digging deeper I'm thinking I was given bad requirements. I found the C code they were using to do the conversion on the old system, and it's hex character 20, not ascii 20, so it's a space. Does that make it any easier to trim the spaces at the end of each record? Sorry for the confusion, I'm just noticing this now that I dumped it and see the 040 (space, hex 20, etc.) characters.

Comment: Yes that should be lot easier. Just use: `sed 's/ *$//' file > _temp` and examine `_temp` file.

Comment: That did exactly what I needed, thanks for all the help anubhava!!! I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer but I will as soon as I can. Thank you!!!

Comment: You're most welcome. I'm very glad that your problem got resolved eventually. In hindsight I think I should have asked you to examine input text at start to see what characters are indeed there using `od -bc` command.

Answer (score 0):

ksh:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    record=${line:0:320}           # the first 320 chars of the line
    echo "${record%%+(\x14)}"      # removes ascii 20 chars from end of record
done < input.file > output.file
```

Let me know if I've mis-read your requirements.

Comment: Glenn, that sounds like what I am looking to do, but I get an error. I forgot to mention that I'm on AIX here, maybe the syntax is different? When I put this in a .ksh file with a static input filename and output filename and try to run it, it says "./readwhile.ksh[2]: record=${line:0:320}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command."

Comment: What version of ksh do you have?

Comment: Sorry, Glenn, I cannot seem to find that out -

$ ksh --version
--version: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.
$ echo $KSH_VERSION

$ echo ${.sh.version}
/bin/ksh: ${.sh.version}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.
$

Any ideas on an alternative method to find the version?

Comment: You might try `what $(type -p ksh)`, but look in your ksh man page to see if the syntax I suggested is valid in your version. It worked for my on ksh "Version M-11/16/88i" on an old Solaris machine.

Comment: Thanks, Glenn. That didn't seem to work for me either. Is the syntax different for doing something like "record=${line:0:320}" based on the ksh version? Is there an alternative syntax? What you outlined is exactly what I need to do, I'm just struggling with actually making it work! I really appreciate your assistance and would love to make this work.

Comment: On AIX, use `ksh93` as `ksh` refers to the older *ksh88*.